# iOS Pixel Access of UIImage results in crash/skewing

Tags: ios, core-graphics, pixel

I am trying to access the pixels of a certain image which has been resized using this block:

```
-(UIImage *)imageResize:(UIImage *)imageResizable scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize 
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[imageResizable drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

... where newSize is the size of an UIView, where I am trying to fit this image.

Now, I am supposed to access the pixels of this image, and do some filtering on it. 
I use the following code block:

```
 -(UIImage*) filter : (UIImage *) image
 {
 CGImageRef imageBuffTarget = [image CGImage];
 CFMutableDataRef pixelDataTarget = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(0, 0,   CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageBuffTarget)));

 NSUInteger width2 = CGImageGetWidth(imageBuffTarget);
 NSUInteger height2 = CGImageGetHeight(imageBuffTarget);

 UInt8 *target_image = (UInt8 *)CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(pixelDataTarget);


// Going forward, I want to do some processing here, on the *target_image data. 


 CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef =  CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
 CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo1 =  kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault |  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
 CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(target_image,    CGImageGetWidth(imageBuffTarget), CGImageGetHeight(imageBuffTarget), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageBuffTarget), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffTarget), colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo1);
 CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (context);
 UIImage *newimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
 CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
 CGContextRelease(context);
 CFRelease(imageRef);

 return newimage;
 }
```

I take the image from the UIView, pass it on to the 'filter' method and set it back to the view.

But, on doing this, **the app crashes** and I get the following error in the console:

```
    <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 1280 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast.
    <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
```

When I change:

```
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(target_image,    CGImageGetWidth(imageBuffTarget), CGImageGetHeight(imageBuffTarget), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageBuffTarget), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffTarget), colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo1);
```

TO

```
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(target_image,    CGImageGetWidth(imageBuffTarget), CGImageGetHeight(imageBuffTarget), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageBuffTarget), 2*CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffTarget), colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo1);
```

(*2 multiplied to the 'bytes per row', which does exceed 1280*)

the app doesn't crash, but the output on the view comes out to be a distorted and skewed version of the original image.

Please note that when I call CGImageGetHeight(imageBuffTarget) and CGImageGetWidth(imageBuffTarget), I get the exact height and width of the ImageView whose size I passed into the imageResize method.

Could you please help me figuring out the mistake in this code.

Thanks in advance.